# SQL get 10 biggest average values

Tags: sql, database

I want 10 rows of table1.

Table2 is many-to-one related to table1.

So every table1 has 0-100 entrys in table2.

table2 has 2 values: the foreign ID of table1 and an int value.

Now I want to get the 10 rows of table1 where `AVG(SUM(table2.int))` is the biggest.
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by AVG(SUM(x))? What is the meaning of "the average of the sum of a set of values"?

Comment: per title, i think you was trying to type MAX(AVG(table2.int))

Comment: Agree with Mark Byers.  The result of a sum is a single value: the average of a single value is always the single value itself.

Comment: you need to add more clarity to avoid every one to guess what you are tying to say. @lukas and andomar, I am sure it can be answered with an ANSI SQL if he gives more clarity on his question. see, thats his first post here

Answer (score 0):

group by table2.foreignIdOfTAble1 order by AVG(table2.int) desc limit 10